# Spring Security SAML Identity Metadata WITHOUT Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-security

I keep seeing the following block of code for registering SAML identity providers:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          adfs:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: https://idp.example.com/issuer
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:idp.crt"
              singlesignon.url: https://idp.example.com/issuer/sso
              singlesignon.sign-request: false
```

However, I have an older project that I need to implement multiple SAML identity providers that is NOT built on Spring Boot, and converting it is not an option (if we were starting the same project today, of course we would use Spring Boot).

How does the above code translate to doing this manually?

Comment: This is perhaps spring config in the form of yaml, are you looking for equivalent configuration in terms of application.properties?

Comment: Are you using the SAML extension project or the `spring-security-saml2-service-provider` module?

Comment: I'm using ```spring-security-saml2-service-provider```, Spring Security version 5.6.0.

Comment: I am not using Spring Boot, so I cannot autoconfigure via application.yaml or application.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by exposing a bean of type `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository`:

```java
@Value("${verification.key}")
File verificationKey;

@Bean
public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations() throws Exception {
    X509Certificate certificate = X509Support.decodeCertificate(this.verificationKey);
    Saml2X509Credential credential = Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("example")
            .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
                .entityId("https://idp.example.com/issuer")
                .singleSignOnServiceLocation("https://idp.example.com/SSO.saml2")
                .wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
                .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credential))
            )
            .build();
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
}
```

The `application.yml` properties that you mentioned, are just a shortcut to declare this bean from Spring Boot. There is a [complete sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/java-configuration/saml2/login) not using Spring Boot in the Spring Security samples repository.

Also, there is an [entire section in Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html#servlet-saml2login-sansboot) teaching how to override Spring Boot auto-configuration (where I took the code block above).

Comment: Thank you. I had just found the same link a few minutes before you posted that. Thank you for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: No worries. Can you accept the answer so other people can refer to it?