# Can not get user info with Spring Security SAML WITHOUT Spring Boot

Tags: spring, saml

I´m working on SAML integration in an older project but I can´t get the user information.

I've guided me with the response of this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275050/spring-security-saml-identity-metadata-without-spring-boot](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

The project has these versions:
spring framework 5.3.24
spring security 5.6.10
opensaml 3.4.6

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class SAMLSecurityConfig {
    private static final String URL_METADATA = "https://auth-dev.mycompany.com/app/id/sso/saml/metadata";

    @Bean("samlRegistration")
    public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {
        RelyingPartyRegistration relyingPartyRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation(URL_METADATA)
                .registrationId("id")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistration);
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class SAMLSecurityFilter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    .antMatcher("/login/assertion")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Controller("loginController")
public class BoCRLoginController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/assertion", method = {RequestMethod.POST},
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> assertLoginData(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        System.out.println(principal);  //here I get a null 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Once I did the login on okta the  class: Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal comes null value.

Could you help me to know why I received null value on the object Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal where suppose have to receive the user information?